Literature on initial placing of agents for Multi Agent Path Finding
I am a physicist working on quantum computing, thus I do not have a good overview regarding the literature about path finding algorithms (in particular multi agent path finding algorithms). I am well aware that this is an active area of research and plenty of literature is available. However, I also need literature regarding a slightly different aspect of path finding algorithms: Consider, for instance, a square lattice, we have agents with labels 0,1,2, and 3. We want to find the shortest path for between agent 0 and 1 as well as between 2 and 3. Now, our task should be to find a good initial placement of the agents prior to performing any path finding algorithm. In this simple example, the solution is easy, as we can simply put 0 and 1 as well as 2 and 3 next to each other respectively - the path finding becomes trivial in this example. If the number of agents increases, the question of this initial placing is becoming less trivial. I assume that this question of the best initial placement is also covered in the literature, however, I could not find any papers answering this question. Could someone give me some references regarding good optimization algorithms / heuristics for finding good initial placements of agents?

Welcome to Scicomp!  Just some questions to clearify what you are looking for:
Is your lattice infinite? Are there other constraints for the placement of the agents? When you say distance, do you mean line-of-flight distance or grid distance (like walking city blocks)? Are you trying to minimize the distances of pairs, or the added distances between all agents?

Are the grid locations exclusive for your agents or may two of them be at the same gridpoint? Are you simulating cooper-pairs or atoms/holes?

Hi @MPIchael, thanks for your comments! the lattice itself is finite and the distance should be measured by a grid distance /manhattan distance. In general, there will be constraints on the placements of the agents, but for the beginning, I just want to keep it simple. Regarding minimizing distances of pairs or added distance - I am not sure yet to be honest, this is something I would like to explore. And yes, the grid locations are exclusive, i.e., only one agent can be placed on each spot. I try to work on compilation for surface code lattice surgery operations, i.e. quantum error correction

Suppose you have $2n$ agents, are you just looking to find the distance between agent $i$ and $i+1$ for even values of $i \in {0, 2, \dots, 2n-2}$? I imagine it's more tricky than this, so please clarify.
